# limit cpu ocupation for script

Tags: linux, central-processing-unit, cpu-usage

How can I limit a cpu usage to my backup script. It does a mysql db dump and backup of my www directory then bzip2 everything, but it takes a bit and during this time a cpu has 100% load. Can I somehow limit a cpu to i.e. 25@ at most, it will take a more time to make a backup but won't halt other background processes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't want to limit its CPU usage by percentt - after all, if the CPU has nothing else to do, it might as well dedicate 100% to your script.

You want to make sure other programs have *priority* over your backup script. To do this, just invoke the script using `nice`:

```
nice mybackupscript
```

This will run the script with low priority, that way it will only get the CPU if other processes are idle.

Answer (score 1):

[cpulimit](http://cpulimit.sourceforge.net/) does exactly what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Often with backup scripts the bottleneck is not CPU but disk I/O.  If this is the case, nice will make little difference to the load on your system.  iostat, which is included with [SYSSTAT](http://pagesperso-orange.fr/sebastien.godard/), can help you investigate further.  Also, [this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/146033/linux-how-to-find-out-whether-the-harddrive-is-causing-a-bottleneck/146036#146036) details other I/O utilities.

[ionice](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ionice) might help some.  However, ionice will only work with the [CFQ scheduler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CFQ).  CFQ became the default with > Linux 2.6.18.  RHEL4 provides the 2.6.9 kernel, however it is still default on RHEL4 and newer.

Comment: +1 for mentioning I/O

Answer (score -1):

Run script with the lowest priority:

```
nice -39 /scripts/script_name.sh
```

Comment: -1 negative values *increase* priority (not to mention that the valid range is -20 to 19 inclusive).

Comment: nice -39 runs with least favorable priority (19)

Comment: Lowest negative value for nice is -20 so it gets overflowed and becomes 19 :) , however I do agree that it's more clearly to use "nice 19" than "nice -39", but they are doing the same thing.

Comment: BTW, the thing about "overflowing" is also nonsense. "nice -n" (n a number) will set niceness to "n". n>19 is the same as 19, so nice -19, nice -20, nice -21... etc. all do the same.